# how to extract information from jpanel

Tags: java, swing, drawing, jpanel

I am trying a project called white board sharing in which I need to get the information from a panel and that information is like some drawings so how can I get it from a panel. In that panel I am drawing some rectangles circles.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to react on mouse events you might want to investigate the following sections of the Java API.

[MouseListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addMouseListener%28java.awt.event.MouseListener%29)

[MouseMotionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addMouseMotionListener%28java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener%29)

Also if you want to react on mouse events that are triggered when the users moves his mouse over a drawn element you might be interested in [Graphics2D](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) and the classes that implement [Shape](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `Graphics` object to the panel for it to paint the items that were drawn.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to think of the board as a view of some model that records an abstract representation of the board's content. As a concrete example, this [`GraphPanel`](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel) has a very simple model containing nothing more than a `List<Node>` and a `List<Edge>`. These two members could be wrapped and serialized as discussed in this [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/BasicJava2/serial.html#data).